# Issue facing with Mule maven munit batch testing?

Tags: mule, anypoint-studio

Doing munit(xml) testing for my maven based mule project.

Here is my sample batch only with logger

```
<batch:job name="sample-mavenBatch">
        <batch:input>
            <logger message="I am in input phase" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        </batch:input>
        <batch:process-records>
            <batch:step name="Batch_Step">
                <logger message="I am in processing phase" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
            </batch:step>
        </batch:process-records>
        <batch:on-complete>
            <logger message="I am in complete phase" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        </batch:on-complete>
    </batch:job>

The corresponding test for the flow
<munit:test name="new-test-suite-sample-mavenBatchTest" description="Test">
        <munit:set payload="#['rasmita']" doc:name="Set Message"/>
        <synchronize:run-and-wait doc:name="Synchronize">
            <batch:execute name="sample-mavenBatch" doc:name="Run Batch sample-mavenBatch"/>
        </synchronize:run-and-wait>
    </munit:test>
```

This runs me to the following exception

Message

```
     : Object "java.lang.String" not of correct type. It must be of type "{interface java.lang.Iterable,interface java.util.Iterator,interface org.mule.routing.MessageSequence,interface java.util.Collection}" (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException)
Element               : /new-test-suite-sample-mavenBatchTest/processors/1 @ b185c7c0-9c20-11e6-9bef-c03fd56639e7
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception stack is:
Object "java.lang.String" not of correct type. It must be of type "{interface java.lang.Iterable,interface java.util.Iterator,interface org.mule.routing.MessageSequence,interface java.util.Collection}" (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException) (com.mulesoft.module.batch.exception.BatchException)
  org.mule.util.collection.EventToMessageSequenceSplittingStrategy.split(EventToMessageSequenceSplittingStrategy.java:65)
  org.mule.util.collection.EventToMessageSequenceSplittingStrategy.split(EventToMessageSequenceSplittingStrategy.java:26)
  com.mulesoft.module.batch.engine.queue.BatchQueueLoader.splitAndLoad(BatchQueueLoader.java:63)
  (98 more...)

  (set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)
********************************************************************************

ERROR - The test new-test-suite-sample-mavenBatchTest finished with an Error.
Object "java.lang.String" not of correct type. It must be of type "{interface java.lang.Iterable,interface java.util.Iterator,interface org.mule.routing.MessageSequence,interface java.util.Collection}" (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException) (com.mulesoft.module.batch.exception.BatchException) (org.mule.api.DefaultMuleException).
org.mule.api.MessagingException: Object "java.lang.String" not of correct type. It must be of type "{interface java.lang.Iterable,interface java.util.Iterator,interface org.mule.routing.MessageSequence,interface java.util.Collection}" (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException) (com.mulesoft.module.batch.exception.BatchException) (org.mule.api.DefaultMuleException).
    at sample-mavenBatch.mule:logger{doc:name=Logger, level=INFO, message=I am in input phase}(sample-maven.xml:18)
    at sample-mavenBatch.batch:input{}(sample-maven.xml:17)
    at new-test-suite-sample-mavenBatchTest.batch:execute{doc:name=Run Batch sample-mavenBatch}(new-test-suite.xml:18)
    at new-test-suite-sample-mavenBatchTest.synchronize:run-and-wait{doc:name=Synchronize, timeout=2000, runAsync=false}(new-test-suite.xml:17)
    at new-test-suite-sample-mavenBatchTest.munit:set{doc:name=Set Message, payload=rasmita}(new-test-suite.xml:16)
    at appleFlow.munit:test{initialState=started, description=Test, ignore=false, abstract=false, id=MunitTestFlow$$EnhancerByMUNIT$$904837f0{new-test-suite-sample-mavenBatchTest}}(new-test-suite.xml:15)
Caused by: org.mule.api.DefaultMuleException: Object "java.lang.String" not of correct type. It must be of type "{interface java.lang.Iterable,interface java.util.Iterator,interface org.mule.routing.MessageSequence,interface java.util.Collection}" (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException) (com.mulesoft.module.batch.exception.BatchException)
    at org.mule.config.RunAndWait.process(RunAndWait.java:52)
    at org.mule.config.RunAndWait$$EnhancerByMUNIT$$b91d97ea.CGLIB$process$0(<generated>)
    at org.mule.config.RunAndWait$$EnhancerByMUNIT$$b91d97ea$$FastClassByMUNIT$$2ac5af50.invoke(<generated>)
    at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:215)
    at org.mule.munit.common.processor.interceptor.MunitMessageProcessorInterceptor.invokeSuper(MunitMessageProcessorInterceptor.java:95)
    at org.mule.munit.common.processor.interceptor.MunitMessageProcessorInterceptor.process(MunitMessageProcessorInterceptor.java:82)
    at org.mule.modules.interceptor.processors.AbstractMessageProcessorInterceptor.intercept(AbstractMessageProcessorInterceptor.java:46)
    at org.mule.config.RunAndWait$$EnhancerByMUNIT$$b91d97ea.process(<generated>)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:108)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.executeNext(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:88)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.execute(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:59)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.executeNext(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:98)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.execute(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:59)
    at org.mule.processor.AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.process(AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.java:102)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:108)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.executeNext(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:98)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.execute(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:59)
    at org.mule.construct.DynamicPipelineMessageProcessor.process(DynamicPipelineMessageProcessor.java:55)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:108)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.executeNext(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:88)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.execute(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:59)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.executeNext(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:98)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.execute(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:59)
    at org.mule.interceptor.AbstractEnvelopeInterceptor.processBlocking(AbstractEnvelopeInterceptor.java:58)
    at org.mule.processor.AbstractRequestResponseMessageProcessor.process(AbstractRequestResponseMessageProcessor.java:47)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:108)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.executeNext(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:98)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.execute(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:59)
    at org.mule.processor.AbstractFilteringMessageProcessor.process(AbstractFilteringMessageProcessor.java:52)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:108)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.executeNext(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:98)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.execute(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:59)
    at org.mule.processor.AbstractRequestResponseMessageProcessor.processBlocking(AbstractRequestResponseMessageProcessor.java:56)
    at org.mule.processor.AbstractRequestResponseMessageProcessor.process(AbstractRequestResponseMessageProcessor.java:47)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:108)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.executeNext(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:88)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.execute(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:59)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:108)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
    at org.mule.construct.Flow$2.process(Flow.java:138)
    at org.mule.construct.Flow$2.process(Flow.java:133)
    at org.mule.execution.ExecuteCallbackInterceptor.execute(ExecuteCallbackInterceptor.java:16)
    at org.mule.execution.CommitTransactionInterceptor.execute(CommitTransactionInterceptor.java:35)
    at org.mule.execution.CommitTransactionInterceptor.execute(CommitTransactionInterceptor.java:22)
    at org.mule.execution.HandleExceptionInterceptor.execute(HandleExceptionInterceptor.java:30)
    at org.mule.execution.HandleExceptionInterceptor.execute(HandleExceptionInterceptor.java:14)
    at org.mule.execution.BeginAndResolveTransactionInterceptor.execute(BeginAndResolveTransactionInterceptor.java:67)
    at org.mule.execution.SuspendXaTransactionInterceptor.execute(SuspendXaTransactionInterceptor.java:50)
    at org.mule.execution.RethrowExceptionInterceptor.execute(RethrowExceptionInterceptor.java:28)
    at org.mule.execution.RethrowExceptionInterceptor.execute(RethrowExceptionInterceptor.java:13)
    at org.mule.execution.ErrorHandlingExecutionTemplate.execute(ErrorHandlingExecutionTemplate.java:60)
    at org.mule.execution.ErrorHandlingExecutionTemplate.execute(ErrorHandlingExecutionTemplate.java:30)
    at org.mule.construct.Flow.process(Flow.java:132)
    at org.mule.munit.assertion.processors.MunitTestFlow.process(MunitTestFlow.java:121)
    at org.mule.munit.assertion.processors.MunitTestFlow$$EnhancerByMUNIT$$904837f0.CGLIB$process$0(<generated>)
    at org.mule.munit.assertion.processors.MunitTestFlow$$EnhancerByMUNIT$$904837f0$$FastClassByMUNIT$$f664bbef.invoke(<generated>)
    at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:215)
    at org.mule.munit.common.processor.interceptor.MunitMessageProcessorInterceptor.invokeSuper(MunitMessageProcessorInterceptor.java:95)
    at org.mule.munit.common.processor.interceptor.MunitMessageProcessorInterceptor.process(MunitMessageProcessorInterceptor.java:82)
    at org.mule.modules.interceptor.processors.AbstractMessageProcessorInterceptor.intercept(AbstractMessageProcessorInterceptor.java:46)
    at org.mule.munit.assertion.processors.MunitTestFlow$$EnhancerByMUNIT$$904837f0.process(<generated>)
    at org.mule.munit.runner.mule.MunitTest.run(MunitTest.java:108)
    at org.mule.munit.runner.mule.MunitSuite.run(MunitSuite.java:49)
    at org.mule.munit.runner.mule.MunitSuiteRunner$1.runSuite(MunitSuiteRunner.java:53)
    at org.mule.munit.runner.mule.MunitSuiteRunner$1.runSuite(MunitSuiteRunner.java:49)
    at org.mule.munit.runner.MunitRunner.run(MunitRunner.java:75)
    at org.mule.munit.runner.mule.MunitSuiteRunner.run(MunitSuiteRunner.java:49)
    at org.mule.munit.remote.MunitRemoteRunner.runTestSuite(MunitRemoteRunner.java:193)
    at org.mule.munit.remote.MunitRemoteRunner.run(MunitRemoteRunner.java:102)
    at org.mule.munit.remote.MunitRemoteRunner.main(MunitRemoteRunner.java:76)
Caused by: com.mulesoft.module.batch.exception.BatchException: Object "java.lang.String" not of correct type. It must be of type "{interface java.lang.Iterable,interface java.util.Iterator,interface org.mule.routing.MessageSequence,interface java.util.Collection}" (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException)
    at com.mulesoft.module.batch.engine.DefaultBatchEngine.load(DefaultBatchEngine.java:419)
    at com.mulesoft.module.batch.DefaultBatchJob.execute(DefaultBatchJob.java:357)
    at com.mulesoft.module.batch.processor.BatchExecuteMessageProcessor.process(BatchExecuteMessageProcessor.java:49)
    at com.mulesoft.module.batch.processor.BatchExecuteMessageProcessor$$FastClassByCGLIB$$c5698262.invoke(<generated>)
    at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:191)
    at org.mule.munit.common.processor.interceptor.WrapperMunitMessageProcessorInterceptor.invokeSuper(WrapperMunitMessageProcessorInterceptor.java:62)
    at org.mule.munit.common.processor.interceptor.MunitMessageProcessorInterceptor.process(MunitMessageProcessorInterceptor.java:82)
    at org.mule.munit.common.processor.interceptor.WrapperMunitMessageProcessorInterceptor.intercept(WrapperMunitMessageProcessorInterceptor.java:42)
    at com.mulesoft.module.batch.processor.BatchExecuteMessageProcessor$$EnhancerByMUNIT$$c5698262.process(<generated>)
    at org.mule.config.RunAndWait$1.process(RunAndWait.java:42)
    at org.mule.Synchronizer.runAndWait(Synchronizer.java:39)
    at org.mule.config.RunAndWait.process(RunAndWait.java:48)
    ... 86 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Object "java.lang.String" not of correct type. It must be of type "{interface java.lang.Iterable,interface java.util.Iterator,interface org.mule.routing.MessageSequence,interface java.util.Collection}"
    at org.mule.util.collection.EventToMessageSequenceSplittingStrategy.split(EventToMessageSequenceSplittingStrategy.java:65)
    at org.mule.util.collection.EventToMessageSequenceSplittingStrategy.split(EventToMessageSequenceSplittingStrategy.java:26)
    at com.mulesoft.module.batch.engine.queue.BatchQueueLoader.splitAndLoad(BatchQueueLoader.java:63)
    at com.mulesoft.module.batch.engine.DefaultBatchEngine.load(DefaultBatchEngine.java:402)
    ... 97 more
```

where as The same test case works in non-maven mule project.

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you please put your entier mule project file without any modification?

Comment: @AlpeshGediya Yes,, but how can I put my entire project in Zip format?

Comment: Put your mule flow file.. See error logs.. Line number 17 has some problem

Answer (score 0):

This is the issue of the input set in Munit. As error message clearly says

`Object "java.lang.String" not of correct type. It must be of type "{interface java.lang.Iterable,interface java.util.Iterator,interface org.mule.routing.MessageSequence,interface java.util.Collection}" (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException) (com.mulesoft.module.batch.exception.BatchException) (org.mule.api.DefaultMuleException).`

Batch input should be Iterable, but you have provided String `#['rasmita']`. Instead of this try to pass array list. You can use MEL or dataweave for the same.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried using transform message. it throws me the following error.  org.threeten.bp.zone.ZoneRulesProvider: Provider org.threeten.bp.zone.TzdbZoneRulesProvider could not be instantiated (java.util.ServiceConfigurationError).

Comment: try with input as ArrayList   `#[['rasmita']]`

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my issues in two ways

```
1) in Set payload as @anupambhusari said use arraylist, so using MEL #[{'rasmita','ananda'}]
2)With transform message which was throwing the below exception org.threeten.bp.zone.ZoneRulesProvider: Provider org.threeten.bp.zone.TzdbZoneRulesProvider

Added the below dependency. 

Test <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mulesoft.weave</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-plugin-weave_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.threeten</groupId>
                    <artifactId>threetenbp</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
```